# DAX code not working with config variable used in a measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table (named Proto) in power-bi desktop as shown below (with 4 columns & around 30k rows).
[image]

I created a measure with the following DAX code. Here, ProtoVal is a table of single column containing unique values of protocol (like SSL, DNS etc). Based on the user selected protocol, i am filtering the above table to contain rows only for the selected protocol.

```
ProtoTotBytes =
VAR SelectedProto = SELECTEDVALUE(ProtoVal[Protocol])
VAR temp1 = FILTER(Proto, Proto[Protocol] == SelectedProto)
RETURN CALCULATE(SUM(Proto[total_bytes]), temp1)
```

The above DAX code works fine. Now in addition to SelectedProto, i wanted to add one more config variable numIP (TopN-IP's being a table of single column containing numerical values 5,10,15,20 etc`TopN-IP's = GENERATESERIES(5, 30, 5)`) where i want to take only the top 'numIP' rows from table temp1. Wrote the code below for that. This works whenever i change the value of SelectedProto but doesn't change when i change numIP ? Can anyone please let me know whey its sensitive to one config variable while it is ignoring another ?

```
ProtoTotBytes =
VAR numIP = SELECTEDVALUE('TopN-IP''s'[TopN-IP's])
VAR SelectedProto = SELECTEDVALUE(ProtoVal[Protocol])
VAR temp1 = FILTER(Proto, Proto[Protocol] == SelectedProto)
VAR temp2 = TOPN(numIP, temp1, [total_bytes], DESC)
RETURN CALCULATE(SUM(Proto[total_bytes]), temp2)
```

Comment: Where from numIP coming?

Comment: @mkRabbani : updated the question above. numIP is the selected value coming from TopN-IP's which is a table of single column containing numerical values 5,10,15,20 etc

Answer (score 0):

It does exactly what you told it to do, look at your code:

```
VAR temp1 = FILTER(Proto, Proto[Protocol] == SelectedProto)
VAR temp2 = TOPN(numIP, temp1, [total_bytes], DESC)
```

in the first line you use FILTER, this is correct, you are filtering
in the second line you are using TOPN, this is only sorting. I believe your intent was, was a filter based on your selection so also here you need to use FILTER.

```
VAR temp2 = FILTER(temp1, numIP = VALUE(RIGHT(Proto[networkIpAddress],1)))
```

In this filter I compare the last digit of the networkIp with the numIP(s) selected by the user

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I couldn't fully understand on what you did above. But when i tried the above change, i got the error : ```Error Message:
MdxScript(Model) (56, 27) Calculation error in measure 'Proto'[ProtoTotBytes]: DAX comparison operations do not support comparing values of type Integer with values of type Text. Consider using the VALUE or FORMAT function to convert one of the values.``` Can you please explain in little more detail about the solution. Thanks.

Comment: The error was an oversight from my side, you cannot compare text with numeric value so I converted the text, see answer